# Where are xmodmap settings saved?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I created my own keyboard layout and loaded it with `xmodmap .Xmodmap`. Now I want to go back to a default layout, but after a reboot the layout defined with xmodmap are still present. What files is modifying xmodmap?

By the way, I'm using Arch Linux, and I just want to have again the layout defined in `/etc/vconsole.conf` (which is the default place to define your keyboard layout with systemd, according to the Arch Wiki).

Comment: Atleast in Ubuntu it resides in `~/.Xmodmap`

Comment: If your ~/.Xmodmap still exists, it is likely loaded on login.  Move it aside and restart X.

Comment: I deleted `~/.Xmodmap` but after a restart still have the same keyboard layout